# Dynamically adding user control to page using place holder

Tags: .net, placeholder, user-controls

I am attempting to add a user control to a place holder. I am placing the user control inside of a list item `<li>` userControl `</li>`, then placing the list item inside of an unordered list `<ul><li>`user control`</li></ul>`, and then adding the unordered list to the place holder, phMain.Controls.Add(myUnorderedList)... Code below:

```
var myListItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
var preview = new UserControls_ChiotsPreview();
preview = (UserControls_ChiotsPreview)LoadControl(typeof(UserControls_ChiotsPreview), null);
myListItem.Controls.Add(preview);
myUnorderedList.Controls.Add(myListItem);
placeholderMain.Controls.Add(myUnorderedList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was the order in which I was loading the control on the page and calling the constructor logic which caused my control to have null values.

```
var myUnorderedList = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
myUnorderedList.Attributes["class"] = "resultClass";
var counter = 0;

foreach (var chiot in chiots)
{
//create list item, can I put the user control inside of here? why not?
var myListItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

//add user control to li
var preview = (UserControls_ChiotsPreview)LoadControl("~/UserControls/ChiotsPreview.ascx");
preview.Name = chiot.Name;
preview.MainPhoto = chiot.MainImage;
preview.Breed = chiot.Breed;
preview.ChampionSireDam = ResolveImage(chiot.ChampionSireDam);
preview.ChampionBloodline = ResolveImage(chiot.ChampionBloodline);
preview.Price = chiot.Price;
preview.Details = chiot.Description;

myListItem.Controls.Add(preview);

//add li to ul
myUnorderedList.Controls.Add(myListItem);

//max column  = 5
counter += 1;

//maximum 5 columns
if (counter == 5 || chiots.Count == counter)
{
try
{
phMain.Controls.Add(myUnorderedList);
```

Comment: It would be nice if the Page.LoadControl method was able to access the user controls constructor values.

Comment: I just came across this in a search...you know that in your original post, the overload you used for `Page.LoadControl` as in `(UserControls_ChiotsPreview)LoadControl(typeof(UserControls_ChiotsPreview), null)` - where you have `null` there, you can send an `object[]` with objects that "match in number, order, and type of the parameters of the constructor to invoke" i.e. the constructor of your control.